# What does "return $q.reject(response)" do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I am a bit confused about what the statement

```
return $q.reject(response);
```

does inside the `responseError` interceptor.

I have gone through [this article on webdeveasy](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) and [one on angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) but they haven't helped.

Here is my code (for reference):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('xyz').factory('errorResponseInterceptor', ['$q', 'toaster', function ($q, toaster) {
        return {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            responseError: function (response) {
                ...
                ...
                //some logic here
                ...
                ...
                if (response.status == 500) {
                        toaster.error({ title: "", body: response.statusText });
                    return $q.reject(response);//what does this statement does and why do we need to put it here?
                }
                return response;
            }
        };
    }]);
}());
```

My Question is:

1. Why do we need to write `return $q.reject(response)`?
2. How does that line affect the angular app (what does it do)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$q` object in Angular allows us to define a promise and handle the behaviour associated with a promise. An example of how we might do this is:

```
var q = $q.defer()

//do something
if(success){
  q.resolve()
} else {
  q.reject()
}

return q
```

What we are doing here is defining a promise object and assigning it to the variable `q`. Then we perform some operation and use the result of that to determine whether the promise returns successfully or not. Calling `.resolve()` on the promise object is indicative of the fact that the promise has returned correctly. By the same token calling `.reject()` on the promise is indicative of the fact that is has failed.

If we consider how we actually use a promise:

```
SomeFactory.getSomething().then(function(data){
  //gets called if promise resolves
}, function(error){
  //gets called if promise rejected
}
```

So in the example you have provided, we are checking to see if the response has a 500 error code, and if it does, we are rejecting the promise thus allowing us to handle the error.

In a `responseError` interceptor you have two choices with regards to what you return. If you return `$q.reject(response)` you are continuing the error handling chain of events. If you return anything else (generally a new promise or a response) you are indicating that the error has been recovered from and should be treated as a success.

With regards to your two points:

1- You need to write that line to indicate that the response should still be considered an error.

2- The effect on the angular app is that the error callback will be called instead of the success callback.

Comment: Interesting! Above answer just talk about philosophy of promise what I am doing is rejecting the response from http interceptor. Can you please relate how your answer is useful in that context?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you asking what the $q.reject line does or are you asking why you need to do it in that context?

Comment: I was asking why do we need to write that statement. and what effect it does to the angular app?

Comment: Ok in that case you need to write that statement because the interceptor has exposed a promise object ($q) which you need to reject in the case of error.